# Ansible script module 'creates:' not generating file

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I am running the script module in a role on a windows machine.

I am attempting to use the "args: creates:" parameter. The script runs but the file that 'creates' is supposed to generate never gets created. When I run the playbook again the script runs a second time.

I've tried changing the file name and directory, I've tried using the environment variable to designate HOME as the root directory but the file never gets generated.

```
---
- name: run script
  script: ./files/script.ps1 PARAMETERS
  args:
    creates: script_has_been_run.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: "The script runs but the file that 'creates' is supposed to generate never gets created."

A: It's the responsibility of the script to create the file. Quoting from [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html#script-runs-a-local-script-on-a-remote-node-after-transferring-it)

> creates: A filename on the remote node, when it already exists, this step will not be run.

The purpose of the parameter `creates` is to make the module idempotent, i.e run the script if the file does not exist. Once the file has been created, by the script, the task will be skipped.

Comment: wow, so I totally missed that. I thought the Ansible task created the file which is why I was so frustrated when I couldn't find it.  Thank you!